# Clear a cache with JSR-107 annotations

Tags: java, jcache

On a REST API, I want to create a single endpoint that clears a specific cache:

`DELETE /cache/{cacheName}`

Is it possible to implement it instead of:

```
public void clearCache(String cacheName) {
    cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear();
}
```

to something like this?

```
@CacheRemoveAll
public void clearCache(String cacheName) {}
```

So I'm avoiding injecting the `CacheManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, no.

Annotations cannot be configured with dynamic objects, only constants can be used. So it's not possible to pass a path parameter `cacheName` to `@CacheRemoveAll` annotation. You can only do that if you know all cache names in advance — by creating a DELETE endpoint for each cache like:

```
@CacheRemoveAll(cacheName="cache-1")
public void clearCache1(){}

@CacheRemoveAll(cacheName="cache-2")
public void clearCache2(){}
```